# Cannot read property 'outlets' of null in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have Angular 4.3.6 project where a template snippet produces this error.

Template block:

`<a [routerLink]="['/article',article?.id]">{{article?.title}}</a>`

Error stack trace:

```
ArticleSpComponent.html:26 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'outlets' of null
    at createNewSegmentGroup (router.es5.js:2967)
    at updateSegmentGroup (router.es5.js:2896)
    at router.es5.js:2914
    at forEach (router.es5.js:593)
    at updateSegmentGroupChildren (
```

The error cause seems to be obvious. article variable is fetched async from Http and initialized after page is rendered so firstly it's null. However I thought that putting ? after this variable allows to avoid this issue.

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`?` in `article?.id` is working fine, but the `RouterLink` directive doesn't like getting a `null` passed.

You could work around using something like:

```ts
<a *ngIf="article" [routerLink]="['/article',article?.id]">{{article?.title}}</a>
<a *ngIf="!article">{{article?.title}}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, Gunter. I thought about such solution. However I suspected there might be a bug in Angular.

Comment: You could see it as a bug, but it's not clear what `routerLink` should do when it gets `null` as part of the route. I don't see any reasonable behavior. A better error message might be helpful though. Please consider reporting a bug (if there isn't one already)

Comment: I ended up using a similar solution, passing in a default route: `[routerLink]="[ '/article', article?.id || 'all' ]"`

Comment: The double pipe operator alternative worked for me. But I'm still seaking for a not-workaround solution :) Thank you.

Comment: I don't think there is one.

Comment: DoubleA's answer is the best solution, since it clears all the console errors!

Comment: Or you can wrap the same routerLink inside ng-container with ngIf clause for `article`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a  [routerLink]="['/language',language.iso639_1 || 'all']" >{{language.name}}</a>
```

I was also facing the same issue (Cannot read property 'outlets' of null
) but the above code that I have written, worked for me.