# How to correctly use SharedModules with Router while testing angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test a (angular 2) component with `routerLink` and `routerLinkActive` but all test cases fail with following error message. (**Note:** I have stubbed the router and other related dependencies. Here's the [reference](https://github.com/angular/angular-ja/blob/master/public/docs/_examples/testing/ts/testing/router-stubs.ts) that I used for the same.).

> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

**I have also noticed that when `routerLink` and `routerLinkActive` are removed from my template, all test cases will run without any errors.**

I think the error is caused by either `RouterTestingModule` or `SharedModule`*(contains component for displaying and validating password input field)*. So I tried removing or adding them to find which is actually causing the problem. Here's what I observed.

- I get '`Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'` if 
  `RouterTestingModule` or `SharedModule` is present.
- I do not get any error linked to router only if I remove both `RouterTestingModule` and `SharedModules` but the elements from the `SharedModules` would not get loaded in the component and some test cases still fail because of that.

TestBed configuration:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({

            imports: [CoreModule,SharedModule,RouterTestingModule],
            declarations: [ MyComponent,RouterLinkStubDirective,RouterOutletStubComponent ],
            providers: [
                FormBuilder,
                { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub },
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, userClass: ActivatedRouteStub}
            ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        })
            .overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
                set: {
                    providers: [
                        {provide: AuthModel, useClass: MockAuthModel}    
                    ],
                }
            })
            .compileComponents();
    }));
```

**ActivatedRouterStub:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ActivatedRouteStub {

    // ActivatedRoute.params is Observable
    private subject = new BehaviorSubject(this.testParams);
    params = this.subject.asObservable();

    // Test parameters
    private _testParams: {};
    get testParams() { return this._testParams; }
    set testParams(params: {}) {
        this._testParams = params;
        this.subject.next(params);
    }

    // ActivatedRoute.snapshot.params
    get snapshot() {
        return { params: this.testParams };
    }
}
```

What changes should I make to solve the issue?

Comment: Can you share the ActivatedRouteStub, sounds like you're not returning an Observable from your stub setups. Also what are your test fixtures? Do you get the error before even the tests are run?

Comment: @KlsLondon Actually my test case fails with following error: _Failed: Error in ./myComponent class myComponent - inline template:80:21 caused by: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined_. Also I have updated the question with ActivatedRouterStub

Comment: @KlsLondon Since the most simple test cases such as `it('Should create component',() => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });` is failing, I think the errors appear before test cases are run.

Comment: this.testParams would be undefined unless you call the setter of that property somewhere before your test runs?

Comment: @KlsLondon Yes. I've called setter in beforeEach() 
`let activatedRoute = new ActivatedRouteStub();
        activatedRoute.testParams = { url: this.requestURL };`

Comment: @KlsLondon Should we provide mocked router if we have imported RouterTestingModule? I found a solution which said there is no need to provide it if RouterTestingModule is present. Since I have routerLink in my template and it [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42039920/8558515) real Router, I tried to remove the Router providers. Now I get `Cannot read property 'outlets' of null`.

Comment: Did you solve this issue. I have the same problem

Comment: @user1188867 I have answered the solution that works for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue. I'll list what changes I made to solve the issue.

1. As I mentioned in the comments, `routerLink` works only on real router. So we need to include **RouterTestingModule** *(include `.withRoutes([{path: 'some/path',component: someComponent}])` if you plan to click on it while testing).*
2. We **need not** provide Router dependencies separately if we have added `RouterTestingModule` already. So I removed both `Router` and `ActivatedRoute` dependency that I provided. Now, the error changed from `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` to `Cannot read property 'outlets' of null`.
3. I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45916133/8558515) out this error occurs when the `routerLink` **is pointing to a null** variable. In my case, the property called `favoriteUrl` that i assigned to `routerLink` was null because of the isolated testing environment. So I manually assigned a value to the property in `beforeEach` function and that solved the problem, atleast for me.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help! :-)

## References:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45916133/8558515

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42039920/8558515

Answer (score 0):

Angular has no way of knowing that you want it to use the activatedRoute variable that you created yourself(as per comment) so it will create default one and use that in DI.  Instead of the current setup for the ActivatedRoute dependency use `{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockInstance}` where `mockInstance` is a mock of `ActivatedRoute`, you can create that with `jasmine.createSpyObj`

Comment: Did not work. Unfortunately same error. I created a class `class MockActivatedRoute {
    params = {
        subscribe: jasmine.createSpy('subscribe')
            .and
            .returnValue(Observable.of(<Params>{url: this.requestUrl}))
    }
}` and provided the class in ActivatedRoute provider.

Comment: Hard to help you when don't have all the code, maybe reproduce the error in jsFiddle project?

Comment: Thank for the help! I got the solution. :-)